# Is there a way to make webpack not show all the chunks it's compiling?

Tags: node.js, webpack, webpack-dev-server

The default webpack CLI output is way too verbose for my liking. As soon as I import React from one of my files, the output explodes, showing all of the chunks (?) being packed:

```
webpack result is served from /
content is served from /Users/me/myproject
Hash: aaaf5afc6582f3222f55
Version: webpack 1.12.14
Time: 1175ms
   Asset    Size  Chunks             Chunk Names
index.js  677 kB       0  [emitted]  main
chunk    {0} index.js (main) 643 kB [rendered]
    [0] ./src/app.js 574 bytes {0} [built] [1 error]
    [1] ./~/react/react.js 56 bytes {0} [built]
    [2] ./~/react/lib/React.js 1.49 kB {0} [built]
    [3] ./~/react/lib/ReactDOM.js 3.71 kB {0} [built]
    [4] ./~/process/browser.js 2.06 kB {0} [built]

...

  [155] ./~/fbjs/lib/mapObject.js 1.47 kB {0} [built]
  [156] ./~/react/lib/onlyChild.js 1.21 kB {0} [built]
  [157] ./~/react/lib/deprecated.js 1.77 kB {0} [built]
  [158] ./~/react-dom/index.js 63 bytes {0} [built]
  [159] ./src/component.js 339 bytes {0} [built] [1 error]
```

I really don't care about all of that extra information. I'd be happy with a way to either:

- Disable the chunks altogether, just showing the overall progress
- Only show my own code, not stuff I'm importing from my node_modules

At the moment my webpack command is `webpack-dev-server --progress`. My webpack config is pretty basic, just specifying entry, output, and loaders for babel and eslint.

Answer (score 11):

From the command line, I haven't been able to find a way to do this.

However, if you have a `webpack.config.js` file, there are two options for suppressing the list of modules ..

```
devServer: {
    stats: 'errors-only'
}
```

or

```
devServer: {
    stats: { chunks: false }
}
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Not sure if I'm doing something totally wrong, but I can't get any of these to work. It still always prints the massive list of modules :( I've also tried adding it to the webpack section of my karma config when running my tests, and it doesn't work there either.

Comment: For whatever it's worth - these both work for me. Running webpack-dev-server 1.16.2

Comment: devServer: {
    stats: { chunks: false }
}

Worked for me.

Comment: The only place this worked for me was 'webpack.base.babel' for those of you using react-boilerplate.

Answer (score 11):

This worked in my case:

```
webpack --hide-modules
```

Comment: searched far and wide - best answer out there

Comment: Does not work in webpack 3 (EDIT: it actually does, as long as you do not pass the `--color` flag as well)

Answer (score 11):

If you have a webpack.config.js in your project, add the following to the returned object of the exports function:

```
devServer: {
    stats: {
        assets: false,
        children: false,
        chunks: false,
        hash: false,
        modules: false,
        publicPath: false,
        timings: false,
        version: false,
        warnings: true,
        colors: {
            green: '\u001b[32m'
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Adding these "stats:" options to the root of the module.exports dictionary in my webpack.config.js, combined with the --hide-modules CLI parameter (as suggested by @artnova) allowed to mute/tune every detail of the output for the webpack package.

Answer (score 5):

There is `webpack` undocumented [option](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/blob/master/bin/webpack.js#L51) `--hide-modules`.
You can pass it to `webpack` from `webpack-dev-server` by adding this line to [webpack config](https://webpack.github.io/docs/webpack-dev-server.html#additional-configuration-options):

```
devServer: { 'hide-modules': true }
```

Comment: Just tried this and it doesn't seem to make any difference. I tried `--hide-modules=true` as well.

Comment: I also found a `--quiet` option for webpack-dev-server. That gets rid of the module/chunk listing, but it also removes any indication at all that the packing has happened when I change the code. So that's probably too *little* information.

Comment: `hide-modules` is webpack option and seems it not passed from webpack-dev-server.

Comment: Nope, that doesn't seem to work either :( On the bright side, I've realised that it only shows the full list on the first run. If I then go and modify a file and save it, the console only shows info about the file I just modified. I can live with that :)

Answer (score 5):

Since Webpack 3+ there is `--display` flag which allows fine-grained control over output:

```
--display=(verbose|detailed|normal|minimal|errors-only|none)
```

Answer (score 0):

In the webpack.config.ts, you can try

```
devServer : {
  stats: 'minimal',
  watchOptions: { 
   poll: undefined,
   aggregateTimeout: 300,
   ignored: /node_modules/
 }
}
```

Hope that works.